# Is there a way to completely disable all RF in macOS Monterrey?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, nfc

Specifically on a MacBook Pro 16" 2021 M1 Max, but also applicable to 2019 & 2021 Mac Minis for my purposes.

For operational security reasons, I am looking for a way to completely disable RF communications, including WiFi, Bluetooth, & NFC if applicable, for non-administrator accounts in macOS, without removing the hardware as some machines have soldered Logic Boards. Either natively within macOS, or with some kind of additional application, is there a way that I can completely disable RF for standard users (only allowing wired networking)?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off WiFi and block it

Go to system pref > Network

[image: wifi]

Enable >require admin to turn on

That will not turn off BT, but BT is small range and has to be paired to work.

Comment: seems like I might have to just physically desolder the cards to achieve what I am looking for.